# What is the best practice for importing modules and models in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I was wondering what the best practice is for importing commonly used modules across many handlers.

Currently I have one file (`myimports.py`) that has all my imports e.g. (this file also includes my models and helper functions)

```
from django.template.loaders.filesystem import Loader
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.template.loader import get_template
from google.appengine.api import mail
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
from google.appengine.api import namespace_manager
from google.appengine.api import taskqueue
from google.appengine.api import memcache
import cgi
import datetime
import django_settings
from random import choice

#commonly used functions
def myfunc(): ...
```

In my handler files, e.g. `main.py`, I import with `from myimports import *` to reuse the common imports.  Is there a better way to break up importing these modules?  Is this a considerable memory impact to import all the modules I may not use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's generally considered a best practice to only import what you actually need and use into any given file. "Shared imports" (and `from ... import *` in general) are considered less than ideal, because it hides where names are coming from and makes it harder to tell whether a given function is actually available.

If you import what you need directly into each file where you need it, it's much clearer both (a) where a given item is coming from (because the import is in the file) and (b) that it is indeed available in the file (again, because the import is right there in the file as well).

Comment: Thanks Amber! I'll be more diligent to make my handlers explicit with the modules they actually use and import them on a file by file basis.

Is it a good idea to create a file of global helper functions and import that file?